# Cannot resolve symbol 'OneSignal'

Tags: android, onesignal

Getting this error while adding OneSignal:

> Cannot Resolve symbol 'OneSignal'

Here is My ApplicationClass.java File:

```
package (Your Package Name);

import android.app.Application;

public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "(Your OneSignal ID)";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // TODO: Add OneSignal initialization here

    // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
}`
```

Comment: Have you added the OneSignal dependencies in your gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

You should add OneSignale dependencies into your gradle file.
These two things should go into your gradle file.

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

You can follow this step by step in their documentation. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup